# Express/React promise stalled

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise, fetch

I have an Express backend server on port 5000 and react front end running on port 3000. I am trying to fetch some data from express post route and return it to front end but my Promise never resolves. It always ends up as "stalled".

util.inspect(messageList) shows my array on server console but my Promise on the front end never resolves.

I'm fetching some data server side on ComponentDidMount like below:

```
class Conversation extends React.Component {
  state = {
    conversations: [],
    messages: [],
    error: null,
    loading: true,
    input: '',
    owner: 'Unassigned'
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { match } = this.props
    const { conversationId } = match.params
    // Make a POST request to our server and pass the conversationId
    this.getMessages(conversationId)
  }

  getMessages(conversationId) {
    return fetch('/search-conversation', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ conversation: conversationId })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((messages) => this.setState({ messages }))
  }
```

**Server Side:**

```
app.post('/search-conversation', (req, res) => {
    conversationId = req.body.conversation

    if (!conversationId) {
      res.send('/error');
    } else {
      console.log(`Success, conv id is ${conversationId}`);
    }
    // call function to go get messages from API
    console.log(`fetching messages for ${conversationId}`)
    return fetch(endpoint)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(({ data }) => data)
      .then((data) => {
        const messageList = data[0].messages.data
        return messageList
      })
      .then((messageList) => console.log(util.inspect(messageList)))
      .catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`))
  });
```

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need the full url in `fetch('/search-conversation'`? I think you do

Comment: it probably never resolves because it may reject - typically, you should have a `.catch` somewhere on the front end code to handle errors

Comment: What do you mean the full url? /search-conversation is just an app.post route where I take the conversationId passed in from client side and fetch some data from external API.

Comment: I'm talking about your frontend method `getMessages`. Your backend is an api right? Your frontend doesn't have any knowledge about how your api is implemented. For you local environment, shouldn't it be `'localhost:5000/search-conversation'`? I coule be wrong, but does that mean I have been working with my local dev env incorrectly all this time or something??

Comment: @Andrew I have a proxy setting in my package.json telling React to use my express server like so:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing [res.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) call on the server side that will send response to the client:

```
app.post('/search-conversation', (req, res) => {
  conversationId = req.body.conversation

  if (!conversationId) {
    res.send('/error');
  } else {
    console.log(`Success, conv id is ${conversationId}`);
  }
  // call function to go get messages from API
  console.log(`fetching messages for ${conversationId}`)
  return fetch(endpoint)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(({ data }) => data)
    .then((data) => {
      const messageList = data[0].messages.data
      res.json(messageList)                         // <-- sending response
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`))
});
```

Comment: Thanks @antonku that seems to have done the trick.  I didn't realize I had to call res.json() server side I thought I could just return the value and have it accessible client side.